# List of Users belonging to a particular group in Cognos

Tags: cognos, cognos-11

I need to find the list of users which belong to a particular group in Cognos by querying the Content store database which is SQL SERVER .

Comment: That depends.  Did you create users in Cognos or are you using an external directory namespace?

Comment: Using Active directory

Answer (score 0):

If you have configured Cognos to use an external directory namespace, like MS Active Directory, information regarding group membership is not stored in the Content Store database.  You'll need to get that directly from MSAD.

Comment: I want to find the list  users present inside a Cognos group.

Answer (score 0):

The following site:  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fc5e762d-0c1e-4b18-ad5b-da475da90afc/ldap-query-for-group-members?forum=winserverDS

Provides the PowerShell script:
Get-AdGroup -Filter {Name -like "Group1" -Or Name -like "Group2"} | Get-AdgroupMember | Select Name

to query the AD groups directly.

To get the group memberships within Cognos,  you can either use the Audit Extensions.  See link https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/ibm-cognos-11-audit-extension/

Or you can capture the incoming SQL using the MSSQL SQL profiler when clicking on a Cognos group member listing.

Comment: I want to find the list users present inside a Cognos group.

Comment: I cannot install Audit extension so i tried using profiler but the querries returned was not which we could use to run on database . It was using multiple stored procedure and the where clause had some run time parameters

Answer (score 0):

```
use Cognos_Prod_ContentStore;
-- list users in each cognos group. Group by group_name
SELECT v_group.name AS group_name,
v_user.ldap_id AS user_name
, CLASSID
, MAPDLOCALEID
FROM dbo.cmreford1 AS v_group_user
JOIN (SELECT cmid user_id,
UPPER (NAME) ldap_id
FROM dbo.cmobjprops33) v_user
ON v_group_user.refcmid = v_user.user_id
JOIN (SELECT cmobjnames.cmid cmid,
UPPER(cmobjnames.NAME) name
, cmobjects.classid
, cmobjnames.mapdlocaleid
FROM dbo.cmobjects, dbo.cmobjnames
WHERE
cmobjects.classid IN (26, 54)
AND cmobjnames.mapdlocaleid = 92
AND cmobjects.cmid = cmobjnames.cmid) v_group
ON v_group.cmid = v_group_user.cmid
order by 1,2
```

Answer (score 0):

-- find the groups that a user has access to in cognos

```
use Cognos_Prod_ContentStore;

SELECT v_group.name AS group_name, v_user.ldap_id AS user_name
FROM dbo.cmreford1 AS v_group_user
JOIN (
    SELECT cmid user_id, UPPER(NAME) ldap_id
    FROM dbo.cmobjprops33
    ) v_user ON v_group_user.refcmid = v_user.user_id
    and v_user.ldap_id like 'cog%' -- ENTER THE USERNAME YOUR SEARCHING FOR
JOIN (
    SELECT cmobjnames.cmid cmid, UPPER(cmobjnames.NAME) name, 
    cmobjects.classid, cmobjnames.mapdlocaleid
    FROM dbo.cmobjects, dbo.cmobjnames
    WHERE
        cmobjects.classid IN (26, 54)
        AND cmobjnames.mapdlocaleid = 92
        AND
        cmobjects.cmid = cmobjnames.cmid
    ) v_group ON v_group.cmid = v_group_user.cmid
ORDER BY 2,1
```